# What algorithm can I use to find the shortest path between specified node types in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, graph-theory, shortest-path

This is the problem:

I have n points (p1, p2, p3, .. pn), each of them can connect to any other with a determined cost x.

Each point belongs to one of a set of point-types (for example "A" "B" "C" "D"...).

The input of the method is the path I want to follow, for example "A-B-C-A-D-B".

The output is the shortest path connecting the points of the type I give in input so for example "p1-p4-p32-p83-p43-p12" where p1 is an A-type, p4 a B-type, p32 a C-type, p83 an A-type, p43 a D-type and p12 a B-type.

The "easy" solution consists of calculating ALL the possible paths but the computational cost is very high!

Can someone find a better algorithm?

As I said in title, I don't know if it exists!

Update:

The key point that prevents me from using Dijkstra and the other similar algorithms is that I have to link the points according to type.

As input I have an array of types and I have to link in that order.

This is an image of Kent Fredric (thanks a lot) which describes the initial situation (in red allowed links)!

[image]

A real life example:

A man wants to visit a church in the morning, go to restaurant and finally visit a museum in the afternoon.

In the map there are 6 churchs, 30 restaurants and 4 museums.

He wants that the distance church-rest-museum is the minimum possible.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly. Isn't that just some kind of minimum spanning tree?

Comment: Do you plan on selling anything at any of these points? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: Wait is it that you can follow only a single node for each letter?

Comment: @EFraim: My impression is that there are multiple nodes of each lettered type.

Comment: @chaos: the question is really whether one letter represents a *path* or a *node*. I've given two solutions which hopefully solve both cases.

Comment: The question needs Clarification: "each point belongs to a set" is misleading, you probably wan to say something like "each point belongs to a set of point-types."

Comment: @EFraim: Oh, I see.  Isn't it that a letter represents a node type?  For example, I may be at p22, which has vertices to p27 (A), p58 (B), p66 (D), and p93 (D), and my usable choices are the vertices to P66 and P93 because my path constraint has D as its next element.

Comment: Its difficult to understand the question, if you can give a visual example of a node-system that represents a sample dataset that would be immeasurably helpful.

Comment: I updated the question, I apologize for my english...

Comment: Andrew Hare:  Please tell me that's intended ironically.

Comment: Alberto, it isn't actually clear whether you're allowed to *revisit* a node in order to satisfy your path constraint.  Might help to clarify that.

Comment: Yes you can revisit a node if you want!

Comment: Ahh, that's interesting.  Dijkstra's reduces to best-first search, then, I believe.  So looks like best-first search is my final recommendation.

Comment: Yes but it's the same to calculate every possible path (according to input rule).

Comment: You keep saying that, but no, it's not.  If your vertex costs are actually different, there are many possible paths that best-first search will not calculate because their costs are higher.

Comment: @chaos, see my updated image, he can take any path to any node as long as it follows the sequence, ie: after a B node, *any* C node is fair game. I think This algo aught to be of use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm

Comment: no: kruskal builds a minimum spanning tree for a connected weighted graph.

Comment: yeah, it would need a bit of modification to work, you cant use it verbatim.... you'd have to have some sort of validation rule that decides whether or not 2 edges can touch.

Comment: TO EVERYONE: read my real-life example :-)
I added it at the end of the question!

Comment: Right.  Best-first search will elide a *huge* number of paths in that example that would be examined by breadth-first or exhaustive search.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Floyd–Warshall algorithm. Here's the pseudocode given by WikiPedia:

```
/* Assume a function edgeCost(i,j) which returns the cost of the edge from i to 
   (infinity if there is none).
   Also assume that n is the number of vertices and edgeCost(i,i)=0
*/

int path[][];

/* A 2-dimensional matrix. At each step in the algorithm, path[i][j] is the shortest path
   from i to j using intermediate vertices (1..k-1).  Each path[i][j] is initialized to
   edgeCost(i,j) or infinity if there is no edge between i and j.
*/

procedure FloydWarshall ()
    for k: = 1 to n
        for each (i,j) in {1,..,n}2
            path[i][j] = min ( path[i][j], path[i][k]+path[k][j] );
```

I had to write a program for an algorithms course about this same problem. This algorithm worked like a charm! Goodluck.

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm has better complexity.

Comment: I can't see how you want to deal with type constraint.

Answer (score 4):

There are many algorithms that will do better than calculating all the possible paths.  [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) is the basic starting point for the family of algorithms I have in mind, [Best-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search) is appropriate because you have vertex costs defined, and if you can get more information about your problem space, you may be able to use [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*) or [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). (In each case, finding the paths from the set of allowed starting nodes.)

Re your edit: Your path constraint (the array of node types you need to satisfy) doesn't prevent you from working with these algorithms; quite the opposite, it helps them all work better.  You just need to implement them in a way that allows the path constraint to be incorporated, limiting the vertices available at each step in the search to those that are valid given the constraint.

Comment: If you use Dijkstra's algorithm you want to have following tuple in priority queue: (cost_so_far, current_vertex, number_of_vertices_visited). Then when iterating through outcoming edges you just ignore edges that lead to not wanted types according to number_of_vertices_visited.

Comment: I can't use A* or Dijkstra.
IF I USE BFS IT'S THE SAME OF CALCULATING ALL THE PATHS!

Comment: You can if you follow the advice.

Comment: Best-first search is not the same as calculating all the paths, because it preferentially explores the ones with lower vertex costs.

Comment: To your re to my edit:
I'm not sure to understand what you said... can I do this?

Comment: At absolute minimum you can use best-first search, yes.  I believe you're correct that you can't use A*.  I'm not experienced enough with Dijkstra's to say for absolute certain, but it looks to me like you can, and niteria appears confident about it.

Comment: If you can revisit nodes, I'm not sure if Dijkstra still works. Dynamic programming is a way to go then.

Comment: Syncing with comments on question, since you can revisit, Dijkstra's algorithm is also out, so that leaves best-first search.  Which, again, is much better than calculating all the paths.

Comment: it isn't better, it' exactly the same

Comment: Um.  Okay.  I guess you're using "calculating all the paths" in a specialized manner that actually means "performing best-first search".  Because normally, "calculating all the paths" means exhaustive search, which best-first search is an enormous improvement upon.

Comment: And really, if best-first search is "calculating all the paths", then what is breadth-first search?  Calculating more than all the paths?

Answer (score 4):

As Jan mentioned, you just need a normal boring shortest path algorithm (like Dijkstra's or [Floyd's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) algorithm); however, you need to transform your input graph so that the output path will respect your path constraint.

Given a path constraint of: A - B - A

Create a new graph `G` and insert all of the vertexes from `A` into `G` with new labels like a_01. Then insert all the vertexes from `B` into `G` and connect the `A` vertexes with the `B` vertexes (edges should be directed towards the newly inserted nodes) copying the costs from the original graph. You then repeat this step with `A` (and any other path components) connecting the newly inserted vertexes to those in `B`. Thus, you create a graph where only the paths that exist satisfy the path constraint. You can then use normal shortest path algorithms.

The key insight is that when you revisit a class you are actually visiting a distinct set of nodes and that you only want edges that connect adjacent classes of nodes.

Comment: @Alberto: This is *not* the same as calculating all possible paths. Just like Djikstra's algorithm isn't calculating all the possible paths in the regular shortest-path problem. It finds the best path without enumerating all the possible paths! Aaron's answer is the correct one. He and niteria (although I don't like the code) are right. The rest are wrong or unclear.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

This is how I presently interpret your problem.

Red arrows are me manually tracing the paths that conform to the given ordering constraint.

Costs are not provided, but it is assumed all links incur a cost, and the link costs are different.

If this accurately describes the scenario you are trying to solve, please say so, so that others can better answer the question.

Comment: However, I don't think he has a start node like you depict; rather, if his path constraint starts with A, he starts from the set of A nodes.

Comment: very similar BUT if the rule is A-B-C I have to link an A-type point to a B-type to a C-type and STOP!!!!

Comment: oh, I was stating with "..." It was ABC repeat :)

Comment: now you are very very near.
BUT AS I WROTE IN QUESTION: 
I have n points (p1, p2, p3, .. pn), each of them can connect to any others

Comment: Er, they are technically, because its not possible to get to those nodes while conforming to the join rule. IE: in my rule, you cant go from C to B, so those nodes *ARE* unreachable.

Comment: Ok but the A node in the bottom right can connect to B node in the middle left that can connect to the C node in the top left.
So... there aren't unreachable nodes. I give you a vote-up!

Comment: I updated the image to better represent the unlateral joins between all nodes, see what you think.

Answer (score 2):

On the revision of your question it seems you ask for one node per letter - in that case it is a simple dynamic programming solution: Calculate all the shortest paths of length 1, which satisfy the beginning of your sequence, between each pair of nodes. Then having for k all such paths for all node pairs, it is trivial to construct for k+1.

Comment: ...but in a clever way. You reuse results from your earlier computation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is pseudocode with dynamic programming solution:

```
n - length of desired path
m - number of vertices
types[n] // desired type of ith node
vertice_types[m]
d[n][m] // our DP tab initially filled with infinities

d[0][0..m] = 0
for length from 1 to n 
  for b from 0 to m
    if types[length] == vertice_types[b]
      for a from 0 to m
        if types[length-1] == vertice_types[a]
          d[length][b] = min(d[length][b], d[length-1][a] + cost(a,b))
```

your minimum cost path is min(d[n][0..m])

you can reduce size of d table to 2 rows, but it would obfuscate the solution

Comment: imho it's much better to make your pseudo-code python-style, that is - no endif/endfor noise: indentation matters. congrats for a correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question you need a shortest path in a directed graph. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm should give you an idea.

regards, Jan

Comment: no, thanks for reply but it's different! Please read my (editeed) question better.

Answer (score 1):

1. Calculate all the pairs of shortest paths within each equivalence block.
2. Now build a graph which has NO inter-class edges, but whose edges between classes match the shortest path within that class, leading to the specific node of another class.

Hope this is clear.

This solution is not particularly efficient, but clearly polynomial.