# Finding shortest path between N sets in a directed unweighted graph

Tags: igraph, shortest-path

I want to find an algorithm for the following problem:
Given a directed graph G with starting point s and N sets of nodes, I need to find a path that starts in the start node and then goes to at least one node of every set.
Not all of the nodes are in the sets- only some of them.
There are no nodes that are in more than one set.

For example:

1. starting point: [n1]
2. First set: [n5,n6,n8,n9]
3. Seconed set: [n2,n10]
4. Third set: [n4,n7]
5. Forth set: [n3]
6. Other nodes: [m1..m7]

Showing the graph edges:

[image: Full example]

In this case a shortest path will be:

- [n1,m3,m4,m5,n3,m6,n2,m7,n9]
- [n1,m1,n7,m5,n3,m6,n2,m7,n9]

This problem is similar to the generalization of the Traveling salesman problem ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_TSP_problem)), but in this case, the graph is directional and unweighted. Also, we have a known start point, we have more than just the nodes in the sets and we can walk on the same node more than once.

I tried starting with a lazy fast way of searching for the closest node from the start to all of the nodes in all of the sets with Dijkstra and then removing the set from the calculation and continue searching for the next closest node from all sets from that point.

It is easy to notice that this way doesn't give the shortest path, but the real problem is that sometimes it falls to a dead-end and returns "no path" even when there is a path.

A naive way I can see that can be used is to create a function to calculate for every specific permutation of sets and use an algorithm like the one suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1143103) for a close but easier problem.

It will take O(|N|! * 2^(the number of all nodes in all the N sets))

Adding the code of the lazy way (sorry for the mess).

```py
    from Queue import Queue
    from my_utils import RGBtoHex
    from igraph import *
    from random import choice
    
    
    class path_info:
        def __init__(self, way, length_of_way, satisfied_goal):
            self.way = way
            self.length_of_way = length_of_way
            self.satisfied_goal = satisfied_goal
    
    
    class graph_actions():
        # Goal point has a "start" node and all other goal points are saved in a dictionary
        def __init__(self, graph, goal_points):
            self.graph = graph
            self.goal_points = goal_points
            self.best_path = list()
    
        def calculate_best_path(self):
            self.best_path = list()
            queued_best_path = scatter(self.graph, self.goal_points)
    
            while not queued_best_path.empty():
                self.best_path.append(queued_best_path.get())
    
            return self.best_path
    
    
    def scatter(graph, goal_points):
        best_path = Queue()
        starting_point = goal_points["start"]
        del goal_points["start"]
    
        paths_dict = dict()
        return find_best_way(best_path, goal_points, graph, paths_dict, starting_point)
    
    
    def find_best_way(best_path, goal_points, graph, paths_dict, starting_point):
        last = -1
        while len(goal_points) > 0:
            vertex_color = known_colors[choice(known_colors.keys())]
            for vertex in goal_points.keys():
                # Find shortest paths from vertex
                # Color vertex
                graph.vs.find(str(vertex).encode('ascii', 'replace'))["Fill Color"] = RGBtoHex(vertex_color)
                # Find shortest path if exist with igraph function
                way = graph.get_shortest_paths(starting_point, vertex)
                if len(way[0]) != 0:
                    if (last != -1):
                        # Taking out the first node that is the end of the last route taken
                        way[0].pop(0)
                    paths_dict[vertex] = path_info(way, len(way[0]), goal_points[vertex])
    
            # Find the closest node
            stage = min(paths_dict, key=lambda x: paths_dict[x].length_of_way)
    
            # Transfer from list to queue
            for step in paths_dict[stage].way[0]:
                best_path.put(step)
                last = step
    
            # Delete the other nodes with of the same group from the goal list
            for key, value in goal_points.items():
                if paths_dict.has_key(stage) and value == paths_dict[stage].satisfied_goal:
                    del goal_points[key]
                    if key != stage:
                        del paths_dict[key]
            del paths_dict[stage]
    
            # Saving the last node of this route
            starting_point = last
        graph.save("states_graph_color.graphml", "graphml")
        return best_path
```

Is there a way that is better than the naive? If not, can I use a heuristic way to do this?
I also wonder if igraph has a trick to this in a more clean way.

Even if only the naive way is possible, I'm not sure how to implement it.